# Javascript Count-Up timer from timestamp in row's column

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

I've got an MVC C# web application that has an index view with a table that has entries in the rows that are in UTC time format.

Instead of showing the time the entry was made, I'd like to use javascript to count up from the time an entry was made. I can do it with razor syntax, but it only updates when the page refreshes.

The column holding the timestamp has an element with the class "Counter".

My question is, where does the setinterval go, and is there a quick and easy way to do this? I've seen a few posts, but most start all the timers at the same time, so how would I pass the "start" value of the timer to the function and use setinterval?

Here is the table html. Any help is absolutely appreciated!

```
<table class="table">
<tbody><tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Time</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Joe Smith</td>
    <td><span class="Counter">3/30/2020 5:34:21 PM</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ray Parker</td>
    <td><span class="Counter">3/30/2020 5:32:56 PM</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Jack Black</td>
    <td><span class="Counter">3/30/2020 5:32:16 PM</span></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you mean that you want to show like `this is created 34 seconds ago`?

There's no native api to show like that. You have to make one by yourself.

```js
// makes milliseconds to easy-readable string
const formatDateTime = ms => {
  const sec = Math.floor(ms / 1000)
  if (sec < 60) return `${sec} seconds`
  const min = Math.floor(sec / 60)
  if (min < 60) return `${min} minutes`
  const hr = Math.floor(min / 60)
  if (hr < 24) return `${hr} hours`
  const day = Math.floor(hr / 24)
  if (day < 7) return `${day} days`
  const week = Math.floor(day / 7)
  return `${week} weeks`
}

const getTimeElapsed = from => {
  const previous = new Date(from);
  const now = new Date(); // get current datetime
  const comparedTime = (now.valueOf() - previous.valueOf());
  // get compared time in "milliseconds"

  return formatDateTime(comparedTime)
}

setInterval(() => {
  const str = getTimeElapsed('3/30/2020 7:10:16 PM')
  console.log(str)
}, 1000)
```

[image: works like this]

Insert the code in HTML by yourself.

Comment: Sort of but in javascript on the view.. Mainly, just to show the live count/time in seconds since an item was entered into the list. So, the counter column span would show "00:16" or "4:16".

Comment: Just edit my `formatDateTime` function. It's just how you format the string.